# How come meat doesn't turn into spirit particles?

Tags: log-horizon

In Log Horizon, Meow's burger meat come from a real animal, but when the animal is killed, why doesn't its body turn into particles and disappear like other monsters?

Comment: Perhaps meat is taken from creatures that are not considered combat material, and so "defeating" them is not the same as killing monsters.

Comment: I have watched something to do with HP and MP and spirit particle.. and if the meat is not rebirthed than it will be limited (much like on earth where we need farm)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's true that the meat or other ingredients used in food are obtained by killing monsters. I must clear the assumption that the monsters don't turn into spirit energy and disappear.

**They do disappear.**

The meat that is used for cooking is actually an item drop from those monsters. Which means that only the monsters that drop such items can be used for cooking.
In the first season of Log Horizon for instance, they started hunting [Imperial Forest Boars](http://log-horizon.wikia.com/wiki/Imperial_Forest_Boar) for food. The meat obtained from that is actually an item drop. However, the wiki also says that a chef class player can also harvest the monster for more meat but how exactly is it done is not explained. 
It might be possible that the monster just drops more meat when a chef class player kills it.

Comment: But how come that boy who try to impress marie bring large boar into the clan hall but meow said large boat taste too strong.. remember that?

Comment: Yeah I remember now and I am not sure about that one. The wiki does say that a chef can harvest more from a monster than what a normal drop offers. But I can't say for sure why it didn't disappear. The only thing that I can think of is that he might not have brought the monster full dead. I am just saying this because I have not so far seen any real phenomena which suggests that some monster won't disappear after dying. That's just how Log Horizon works. It might be that they just didn't think about it when they created that scene.

Comment: Ok. maybe chef can harvest more by doing it manually hehe.. i think i also saw giant crab boiled inside huge pan in beach scene.. but never had i seen an item drop like in Minecraft lol.. :3

Comment: I will accept this for now until further investigation xD

Comment: I understand what you are saying but to be really honest and I really appreciate your sense of question and curiosity. But it is the truth that sometimes, things are much more simpler than they seem. There's not always a well thought explanation behind everything. But this is all we know for now. There might be a better explanation.

Comment: if there is only a new season that could explain this xD

Comment: The wiki says chef can use the whole animal while combat player should not kill the boars as it might only drop two kg. So, they just capture it and then give it to chef in which the chef can use the whole thing. So probably when the boar is half dead, chef can use a skill to cut the boar into pieces and then register the pieces of meat as ingredient item with spirit bubbles flying away xD

Comment: Sounds like a possibility but still not a confirmed fact. We might be able to see more interesting theories on this.